# Help in solving the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(a-x)}{x(x^2y^2 - b)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the solutions to the following differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(a-x)}{x(x^2y^2 - b)}\quad\quad(1)$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

To be honest I haven't made any progress. I will, however, mention what I have tried.

First of all I tried partial fraction decomposition (after supposing that $b\geq0$) to see if I can convert $(1)$ to a known form but didn't end up anywhere (besides, I don't really have much experience with differential equations and don't know a lot of techiques/theorems so it might be the case I missed something).

I also tried to play around with $(1)$ like I demonstrate
\begin{align}
(1) \implies \frac{y'}{y}=\frac{a-x}{x^3y^2-xb}&\implies x^3yy'-bx\frac{y'}{y} = a -x \\
&\iff \frac{1}{2}x^3\left(y^2\right)' - \frac{b}{2}x\left(\ln y^2\right)' = a - x \\
&\iff \frac{1}{2}x^3\left(e^w\right)' - \frac{b}{2}x\left(w\right)' = a - x,\quad w=\ln y^2
\end{align}
The last expression seems more solvable, but perhaps it doesn't really help that much.
I had a few other ideas as well but they are all based around writing $(1)$ differently in hopes something comes up.

---

Any solutions/hints would be appreciated. Keep in mind that I am not sure if $(1)$ actually has solutions, but I would obviously want to know if that's th case.

Comment: Letting $y(x) = \sqrt{b-z(x)}/x$ gives $z' = 2(z - b)(z+x-a)/(x z)$. Maybe helpful?

Comment: Are you sure that $b\neq 0$ ? (joke)

Comment: Probably : *"Abandon all hope ye who enter here."* (as wrote Dante  Alighieri in the *Divine Comedy*)

Comment: What is the context for this differential equation?

Answer (score 2):

**This is not a solution.**

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(a-x)}{x(x^2y^2 - b)}$$
More simply with $u=y^2$:
$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{2u(a-x)}{x(x^2u - b)}$$
Note that for $a=0$ this is [Riccati's differentialequation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) :
$$2u\frac{dx}{du} =-x^2u + b$$
This can be trabnsformed into a second order linear differential equation with variable coefficients that's not easy to solve in most cases. So you can't even expect a solution with the simple case $a=0$. As Claude Leibovici
pointed in the comment you can solve the original DE for some cases ( as $b=0$). But you can hardly find a solution for any $a$ and $b \in \mathbb {R}$.